# 仮想マシン起動時にエラーが発生する

Tags: android, java, android-studio

Android Studioでアプリを作っています。仮想マシンを起動したら、以下のようにエラーが出ました。
長くてどこをどう読めば良いのかわかりません。
わかる方いらっしゃいましたら教えてください、どこが間違っているのでしょうか？

> --------- beginning of crash
>   07-03 21:29:28.913 2098-2098 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                        Process: , PID: 2098
>                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{teamgirls/teamgirls.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                                                                            at yurihasuike.teamgirls.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
>                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child
>                                                                            at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.addView(HorizontalScrollView.java:243)
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839)
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
>                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                                                                            at teamgirls.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24) 
>                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
>                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Comment: 仮想マシンとはエミュレーターの事でしょうか。

Answer (score 4):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{teamgirls/teamgirls.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child
```

とのことなので、 `MainActivity` に使っているレイアウトファイル内で `HorizontalScrollView` 要素の直下に複数の子要素があるのではないでしょうか。複数の要素を ScrollView 内に並べたい場合は、ScrollView の直下に RelativeLayout や LinearLayout を置いて、その中に配置すると良いと思います。

Answer (score 2):

スタックトレースをそのまま上から一行ずつ読めばいいのですよ。
まず気になったところ

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{teamgirls/teamgirls.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child

の所から、XMLファイルに間違いがある可能性があることがわかります。(XML の33行目)

> at yurihasuike.teamgirls.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)

から、
作ったアプリのMainActivityのonCreateメソッドで発生している可能性があることが分かります。
恐らく `setContentView(R.id.layoutName)`で発生しているのでは？

Comment: XML ファイルのエラーであることはご指摘の通りだと思いますが、`onCreate()` 内でエラーが発生しているのは、そこで `setContentView()` が呼ばれてレイアウトファイルの inflate に失敗しているからで、スレッドは関係ないのではないかと思います。

Comment: そう思いましたが一応書いておきました。setContentView()は追記します